# Is it safe to delete branch file under .git/refs/remotes/origin/ which is already deleted on remote?

Tags: git, github

I have a branch `test` in local, and then push it to GitHub

```
git push -u origin test
```

then this branch is merged into master and deleted using Github's `Delete branch` by admin.

Then I delete this local branch `git branch -d test`, but it still shows in `branch -va` as
`remotes/origin/test`, and cannot be delete by `git push -u origin --delete test`.

How can I make it not shows in `branch -va`?
Can it done by deleting .git/refs/remotes/origin/test, and is it safe in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual thing is:

```
git remote prune origin
```

which should clean up the whole business.

Answer (score 1):

There are two easier, safer ways to delete the branch.

This will fetch branches from `origin`, and delete (prune, `-p`) branches that no longer exist on origin.

```
git fetch -p origin
```

You can also delete remote branches with `git branch`

```
git branch -r -d origin/test
```